# correcting java code for more scalability

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, fasterxml

I am using a spring-boot application and fasterxml for deserializing my request. While stress testing my java application using jmeter many nio threads are going into TIMED_WAITING state.The statement on which they are waiting is,
`mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), MyRequest.class);`

Below is the extract from thread-dump,

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-1415" #88733 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f98c03d1800 nid=0x2240f in Object.wait() [0x00007f9744dcb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1244)
    - locked <0x00000007762846e0> (a java.util.concurrent.Semaphore)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1158)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:736)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:42)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:247)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:362)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMoreGuaranteed(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2427)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2407)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeArray(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:434)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeArray(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:434)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:70)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4014)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3071)
    at com.myapp.controller.MyController.populate(PublishController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor140.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.myapp.security.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityOAuthFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    - locked <0x0000000776284588> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Nearly 200 nio threads are in the same state. What could be done to make it the code more scalable so that we will get higher throughput.

Comment: Make sure you use the [Apache Portable Runtime (APR) based Native library for Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html): *"Tomcat can use the Apache Portable Runtime to provide **superior scalability, performance, and better integration** with native server technologies."*

Answer (score 2):

OK, so if I am reading that stacktrace correctly, this is a worker thread that is processing a Servlet request, and it is blocked in a call to `populate` in your `MyController` class.  The `populate` method appears to be deserializing JSON from a stream that is reading from an HTTP connection.  I'm not sure if this is the POST data from the original request, or response data from a request sent to a back-end server.  Either way ...

If you have lots of threads in this state, the most likely problems are:

- There is network congestion on the network path that the JSON is being fetched from.
- The source you are reading the data from cannot keep up.
- Your server cannot keep up.

There is no magic bullet for making a service like this more scalable.  The possible solutions *may* include:

- Increase your front-end (or back-end) network bandwidth.
- Tuning the comms stack; e.g. using [APR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html) as suggested by Andreas<sup>1</sup>.
- Replicate the front-end server and put a load balancer in front of it.
- Improve the performance of the back-end services.
- Investigate changing your application design so that it isn't necessary to pass so much data between the front-end and the user and/or the back-end and the front-end.
- Investigate whether caching might reduce the front-end / back-end traffic.
- If the bottleneck is CPU rather than I/O, consider replacing JSON with a representation with lower serialization / deserialization overheads.

But before to try to apply a solution, you first need to understand what the actual bottleneck in your system is.  Only you can do that ...

---

<sup>1 - However, if you have 200 threads stuck like this, I'm pretty sure that APR will only get you part of the way to addressing your current scalability issue.  And certainly it won't take you to the next level.</sup>